# Get GPS Location instantly via Android app

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, android-location

all. I am writing an android app about GPS locations.

I tried it on emulator and entered the latitude and longitude manually, and it worked fine.
However, my problem is: on the real device, in debugging mode, to go the next class by using intent can only be achieved when location is changed. If I start the app directly, I can see the blinking GPS icon, but the app will only stay here, and won't start the next activity. It seems that the variables in the onLocationChanged() will never be changed.

I have heard that to get the location instantly is to use the getLastKnownLocation() method. But I failed to get where I should use it.

Here is the class of how I use the LocationManager to get the locations.

Is there any solutions? I am quite confused. Thank you very much!!

```
    public class mainMenu extends Activity{

private LocationManager locationManager = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent i3 = new Intent();
            i3.setClass(mainMenu.this, police.class);
            i3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mainMenu.this.startActivityForResult(i3,0);


        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent i3 = new Intent();
            i3.setClass(mainMenu.this, ambulance.class);
            i3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mainMenu.this.startActivityForResult(i3,0);


        }
    });

    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent i3 = new Intent();
            i3.setClass(mainMenu.this, fire_station.class);
            i3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mainMenu.this.startActivityForResult(i3,0);


        }
    });



        locationManager = (LocationManager)mainMenu.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000 , 0, new MyLocationUpdater());

        String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



}



public class MyLocationUpdater implements LocationListener{ //change location interface
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //          store the location data
    //          get the best record



        Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        Double lon = location.getLongitude();

        System.out.println("The latitude is " + lat + "and " 
                + "the longitude is "+ lon);


        Double lat11 = lat - 1/69.0;
        Double lat12 = lat + 1/69.0;
        Double lon11 = lon - 1/42.0;
        Double lon12 = lon + 1/42.0;

        StaticVariables.latS1 = lat11.toString();
        StaticVariables.latN1 = lat12.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonW1 = lon11.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonE1 = lon12.toString();

        Double lat111 = lat - 2/69.0;
        Double lat121 = lat + 2/69.0;
        Double lon111 = lon - 2/42.0;
        Double lon121 = lon + 2/42.0;

        StaticVariables.latS11 = lat111.toString();
        StaticVariables.latN11 = lat121.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonW11 = lon111.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonE11 = lon121.toString();

    //          ==================================================
    //          ambulances

        Double lat21 = lat - 3/69.0;
        Double lat22 = lat + 3/69.0;
        Double lon21 = lon - 3/42.0;
        Double lon22 = lon + 3/42.0;

        StaticVariables.latS2 = lat21.toString();
        StaticVariables.latN2 = lat22.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonW2 = lon21.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonE2 = lon22.toString();

        Double lat211 = lat - 5.5/69.0;
        Double lat221 = lat + 5.5/69.0;
        Double lon211 = lon - 5.5/42.0;
        Double lon221 = lon + 5.5/42.0;

        StaticVariables.latS21 = lat211.toString();
        StaticVariables.latN21 = lat221.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonW21 = lon211.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonE21 = lon221.toString();

    //          ===================================================
    //          fire stations

        Double lat31 = lat - 2/69.0;
        Double lat32 = lat + 2/69.0;
        Double lon31 = lon - 2/42.0;
        Double lon32 = lon + 2/42.0;

        StaticVariables.latS3 = lat31.toString();
        StaticVariables.latN3 = lat32.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonW3 = lon31.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonE3 = lon32.toString();

        Double lat311 = lat - 2/69.0;
        Double lat321 = lat + 2/69.0;
        Double lon311 = lon - 2/42.0;
        Double lon321 = lon + 2/42.0;

        StaticVariables.latS31 = lat311.toString();
        StaticVariables.latN31 = lat321.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonW31 = lon311.toString();
        StaticVariables.lonE31 = lon321.toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(mainMenu.this, getPhoneNumber.class);
        mainMenu.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getLastKnownLocation` method does not trigger an `onLocationChanged` event. One way to refactor your code would be to move the logic that acts on a `Location` to a separate method and then call that method both after you call `getLastKnownLocation`, and from your `onLocationChanged` method.

Bear in mind that there is no guarantee that `getLastKnownLocation` will provide a meaningful `Location`, since you the device might have moved since the last location update.

Example code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ....
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    updateLocation(location);
}

public class MyLocationUpdater implements LocationListener{ //change location interface
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateLocation(location);
    }
    ...
}

void updateLocation(Location location) {
    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lon = location.getLongitude();

    // the rest of the code from onLocationChanged
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But as I did in the way you told me, the app just stopped unexpectedly. I check the log in DDMS and it says the crash was caused by the updateLocation() method. Then I remove the intent and try to stop it from starting the next activity, it crashes too.

Comment: Can you provide any more details about why it crashes? Chances are the location received from `getLastKnownLocation` is null.

Comment: Yes, it was because of the NullPointerException. Maybe it takes a few seconds to minutes to get a fixed GPS location. As I remove the updateLocation() from the onCreate() method, it seems that it still doesn't start the next activity after I have waited for 5 minutes. I can see the blinking icon of GPS.

Answer (score 0):

getLastKnownLocation() is faster after a connection has been established with the GPS satellite. For the first time, it will return null, or no value till no connection is established.
You can add a GpsListener to know when the location is obtained. Search about "how to get a gps fix" and you might get answer to your question

Comment: Thank you very much! May I know a little more about it? It works fine if I manually enter the gps data. I think it is because it calls the onLocationChanged() method. However, it doesn't call the method when the location doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem before..but I have got the solution..this is the simplest way to get location instantly.

```
public class LocationFinder extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;
    Location currentLocation;
    double currentLatitude,currentLongitude;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@ Inside LocationFinder onCreate", "LocationFinder onCreate");

        FindLocation();

    }

    public void FindLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                updateLocation(location);

                Toast.makeText(
                        LocationFinder.this,
                        String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
                                + String.valueOf(currentLongitude), 5000)
                        .show();

                }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }


    void updateLocation(Location location) {
            currentLocation = location;
            currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            textView1.setText(String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
                    + String.valueOf(currentLongitude));

        }
}
```

Don't forget to Give permission in Manifeast.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
public static Context mContext;
private double latitude, longitude;
 public LocationManager mLocManager;
// *******This is the new Code start on 11/4/2011 at 3 o'clock


/**
 * This is the Home Button if user Login then it is move to TennisAppActivity otherwise move to Login  
 *
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homelayout);


    mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            this);
    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);
    locationUpdate();
    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                DefaultDisplay.class));

                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonProfile))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                MyProfile.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","MyProfile");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonNotifications))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                ShowAllNotificationActiviry.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","ShowAllNotificationActiviry");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonFavorites))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                FavoritesActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","FavoritesActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

            ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonMore))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                MoreListActivity.class));
                }
            });

}

public void locationUpdate()
{
    CellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();
}


public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    GUIStatics.latitude=location.getLatitude();
    GUIStatics.longitude= location.getLongitude();
    Log.v("Test", "IGA" + "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude);
    //mLocManager.r

    getAddress(latitude, longitude);
    if(location!=null)
    {

    mLocManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude,
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
     if(arg1 == 
            LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) { 
                                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
            "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        } 
                        else if(arg1== LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE) { 
                                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
            "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        } 

}
```

}

This is the code i have use it for finding the device location with the help of latitude and longitude and we also call getLastLocationUpdate in this code.
I hope this is very help full to you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! As I only need the longitude and latitude, I don't think I have to use the Geocoder. Is there any simple way to get them both quickly when gps starts?