# Can't call method in onCreate()

Tags: android

There is a problem on my Android app. If I put a method inside onCreate(), the whole app will crash.

Here is the code

```
private LocationManager locationManager = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i3 = new Intent();
            i3.setClass(mainMenu.this, police.class);
            i3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mainMenu.this.startActivityForResult(i3,0);
        }
    });

    locationManager = (LocationManager)mainMenu.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000 , 0 , new MyLocationUpdater());

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}
```

The updateWIthNewLocation(Location location) method is outside the onCreate();
I can't call it successfully inside the onCreate().

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide log of the error ?

Comment: Where is `updateWithNewLocation()` defined? You don't show it anywhere in your code. Also, what is the error you receive in LogCat?

Comment: I mean the updateWithNewLocation() is outside just below the onCreate() method. It has been defined there. I simply wonder why it cannot be called inside the onCreate() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to learn to use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error.

My guess is that you are crashing with a `NullPointerException`, because `location` is probably `null`. It may take seconds to minutes before you will have a location after calling `requestLocationUpdates()`. If this indeed is what you are encountering, modify your application to remove the `getLastKnownLocation()` call and move your `updateWithNewLocation()` call to the `onLocationChange()` method in `MyLocationUpdater`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The message in the log is the NullPointerException! Actually it is the part of my problem, would you love to help me to solve the whole problem? Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068614/get-gps-location-instantly-via-android-app

Comment: @KittenTom: You already have three answers on that question. Two at least seem correct.